# What architecture do block3 and stack3 from keras.applications.resnet correspond to?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

In [keras.applications.resnet](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/894501ac460723d1d7dcc1c0168876537f0be452/keras/applications/resnet.py#L346-L437) there is block3 and stack3. Which architecture of ResNet do they come from?

I am implementing ResNet V1.5. I had to redefine locally in my project block1 from the same package in order to:

- remove the bias from the convolution layers,
- change the shortcut length to 2 instead of 3 to build ResNet18/Resnet34.

I'd rather not have to redefine the building blocks of the model in order to change just a line or two in the already provided implementation by the upstream TensorFlow 2 - if possible.

I was wondering what block3/stack3 is actually doing. Hence my question is, which architecture does block3/stack3 come from? Can I use it to build ResNet V1.5?

Comment: I posted the same question on: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51550